# Can i use PutDatabaseRecord processor to directly upsert into apache Kudu?

Tags: apache-nifi, kudu

I'm trying to sync Mysql with apache Kudu, I used CaptureChangeMySql processor to Fetch New Update/Insert Records (in JSON Format), How can I use PutDatabaseRecord to put/update the data into Kudu?

note that I'm doing syncing in database level not only a specific table with a fixed schema

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apache Kudu doc](https://kudu.apache.org/docs/kudu_impala_integration.html), you should be able to insert records into a Kudu table using Impala. Depending on the version you may have automatic access to the table (meaning Impala already "knows about" the Kudu table) or you might need an external table created in Impala that sits atop the Kudu table (see the aforementioned doc). Either way you should be able to use the Impala JDBC driver in PutDatabaseRecord or any of the SQL-based processors (like PutSQL if you need to create the table in your flow, for example).

Alternatively you can try the PutKudu processor, which has been in Apache NiFi since version 1.4.0 (via [NIFI-3973](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3973)).